# Check if SqlTransaction is rolled back

Tags: c#

In my application I create a sql transaction

```
SqlTransaction importTrans = GPConnection.BeginTransaction();
```

And then I call several stored procedures in that transaction. If one of the stored procedures fails, it logs the error and it rolls back.

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    cError.LogException(ex);
    importTrans.Rollback();
 }
```

My question is: **Is there a way for me to know, before I call the next stored procedure, that the transaction has been rolled back?** Here's my code with a commented version of something I want to do.

```
using (SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand("taHR2APP13", importTrans.Connection, importTrans))
 {
    oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oCmd.Transaction = importTrans;
   //if (!importTrans.IsRolledBack)
    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: what's the point you are trying to achieve?, your code will jump to the catch block and not execute the rest of the code in case of an exception?

Comment: use TransactionScope class.

Comment: @Pleun The transaction executes several stored procs. If one rolls back, it still tries to do all of them but fails.

Comment: Then why do you only roll back in case of an Exception... Your try catch will either catch the exception (and the other SP's will not execute) or it will not but in that case your LogException will also not be caught